# Ip Address: Does Lotus Notes Application have the Request and Response objects

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

Hi all as I am new to lotus notes applications have a doubt regarding request and response objects are present or not.

Let me take one example. I have a task to generate the IP Address of the client machine whoever is using my lotus notes web application. But when i use this below java code using agents it is giving me the Windows server IP Address instead of client IP address who has used my application.

```
InetAddress thisIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
System.out.println("IP ADDRESS:;::"+thisIp.getHostAddress());
```

But when it comes to java we have request and response objects where we can use proxy and capture the IP from the client machine.

Can anyone tell is it possible to use some other keywords instead of request and response.

Comment: You said this is an agent. Obviously it is running on the server. What kind of agent is it?  What is the trigger that runs the agent? And what kind of client? Is it a Lotus Notes client or a web browser client.  (If it is a web browser client, you should edit your question to specify that it is about Lotus Domino, not Lotus Notes.)

Comment: @RichardSchwartz It is a Java Agent and this above code is Java Code . I doubt that we can capture the client ip address (when he log in into the application using URL)

Comment: If it's a web agent run via a URL, the browser sends the IP address to the server and you can capture it. See @Duston's answer below.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz Can you please let me know in depth what i have to do to capture the Ip address of the client machine who ever uses my URL in lotus should i create a java agent or normal lotus notes agent. how duston has said

Comment: Duston has answered you. If you are writing agent code, then doc.getItemValue("Remote_Addr") will get you the IP address.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz I tried and got the remote ip address correctly thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a web application, the client's address is a CGI variable called REMOTE_ADDR.  No need to get any fancier than that.  Just as an aside you have access to Java and all (or at least most) of its might within agents as well, but you don't need that for just the remote Web client's IP address.

Comment: Can you please let me know in depth what i have to do to capture the Ip address of the client machine who ever uses my URL in lotus should i create a java agent or normal lotus notes agent.

Comment: Put a computed field on your form called Remote_Addr and use the formula Remote_Addr.  http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_TABLE_OF_CGI_VARIABLES_3561.html

Comment: I tried this below code and your explaination was very much worthy thanks again. 
Sub Initialize
Dim session As NotesSession
Set session = New NotesSession
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Set doc = session.DocumentContext
Print "IP address =" + doc.Remote_Addr(0)
End Sub